# How to use two argument in if else clause in U-SQL

Tags: u-sql

I want to use a Null checking and 0 checking on two different column in if else condition in **U-SQL**. But it is throwing me error. I guess it is not taking the Null checking expression with 0 values checking.

```
@ctetemp=
SELECT 
    gvo.TcontainerUnitno,
    gvo.TcontainerETD,

   (gvo.TlotMeasurement IS NULL || cte1.SumTlotMeasurement== 0 ) ? 

 ( 1.0 / (cte1.NumberOfShipments == 0 ? 1 : cte1.NumberOfShipments)) :

 (gvo.TlotMeasurement / cte1.SumTlotMeasurement) AS ConVolPct

FROM @GvoFinal AS gvo

INNER JOIN @cte AS cte1

ON 
gvo.Tcontainerunitno = cte1.UnitNumber

AND gvo.TcontainerETD = cte1.TcontainerETD
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuHW3.jpg)

Appreciate if get quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a valid .NET expression there. So try this:

```
(gvo.TlotMeasurement == null|| cte1.SumTlotMeasurement== 0 ) ?     
 ( 1.0 / (cte1.NumberOfShipments == 0 ? 1 : cte1.NumberOfShipments)) :    
 (gvo.TlotMeasurement / cte1.SumTlotMeasurement) AS ConVolPct
```